# Benefits of running toISOString() on a server log date object

Tags: date, koa, toisostring

I've been looking into Koa.js recently as a next-gen option for running a server (looks good so far...) and came across the following code in an API example:

```
function *reqlogger(next){
  console.log('%s - %s %s',new Date().toISOString(), this.req.method, this.req.url);
  yield next;
}
```

Most of this code looks pretty good, but I'm not sure whether to leave `toISOString()` in. The first `console.log` parameter(s) is formatting the result as string(s) anyway, so why would I want to bother converting the string to ISO format?

Are there any additional benefits I might see down the line to declaring like this? Are there particular functions that prefer date objects in ISO format, for example, or is it just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: ISO 8601 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format is simply a common, standardized format which is a quality you want when you're going to be parsing them later as you tend to do with log files. `JSON.stringify` also converts dates into ISO strings. It's better to be explicit about your formats than leaning on string coercion. I'm not even sure if the result of `String(new Date())` is a standard format. Best to stick with a nice common format like ISO 8601 that everyone knows and loves.

Comment: @danneu if you offer that as an answer I'll accept it.